# Can't install therubyracer in JRuby

Tags: ruby, linux, jruby, rvm

I've installed RVM and then Jruby, this the version that i get when i type: jruby -v:

jruby 1.6.5.1 (ruby-1.8.7-p330) (2011-12-27 1bf37c2) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.7.0_02) [linux-i386-java]

The problem is that I can't install therubyracer gem, i get this when i try to install by jruby -S gem install therubyracer:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5.1/bin/jruby extconf.rb
WARNING: JRuby does not support native extensions or the `mkmf' library very we$
Check http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/Home for alternatives.
Checking for Python...Unable to build libv8: Python not found!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5.1/bin/jruby
```

I also tried with --1.9 parameter, to force to use another ruby version, but it fails anyway. Even I tried to install libv8, but i get the same error above.

Any ideas?
I have CentOS 5.7

Comment: Do you have Python installed?

Comment: "Package python-2.4.3-44.el5_7.1.i386 already installed and latest version"

Comment: It may not work with JRuby as the message explains. JRuby's support for C extensions is not as good as the regular Ruby. Is it possible to use a different JavaScript back-end?

Comment: According to [therubyracer docs](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) it requires Python > 2.5 in order for V8 to compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the [Ruby Rhino](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyrhino).

Comment: Worked very well with this gem, i only had to change the gemfile and change the therubyracer for rubyrhino, and bundle install. Then i just run jruby --1.9 -S rails server with no problems :). When I tried without --1.9 parameter, i got some errors, but i assume it's normal because i made all previous steps with --1.9 parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, in your Gemfile it's:

```
gem 'therubyrhino'
```

followed on the command line with:

```
jruby -S bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, but defining therubyrhino in the Gemfile didn't solve my problem, bundler kept trying to install libv8.

That happened because I defined  twitter-bootstrap-rails gem in the Gemfile, and it depends on the less gem (that depends on therubyracer), so I changed the less gem to use the static branch that not depends on less (as suggested on the issue https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/22):

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => "git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git", :branch => "static"
```